# Set value of a key in actions

Tags: react-native, redux

I want to set the value of a depending key in an action to set the Picker value like this function:

```
  onValueChange = (key: string, value: string) => {
    const newState = {};
    newState[key] = value;
    this.setState(newState);
  };
```

I have 2 Pickers and depending on the key I want to set the value of that key. I could do this:

```
  onValueChange = (key: string, value: string) => {
    const newState = {};
    newState[key] = value;
    actions.setGrade(value);
  };
```

If the key was Grade but do I have to check with an if statement to see what the key is or is there a more clean way to it? This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
export function setPicker(key, value){
  return {
    type: types.SET_PICKER,
    key,
    value
  };
```

And in my reducer:

```
case types.SET_PICKER:
  return {
    ...state,
    {action.key}: action.value
  };
```

So I could set it like:

```
actions.setPicker(key,value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to check the value of key, you could create specific actions.

```
export function setPickerGrade(grade) {
  return {type: types.SET_PICKER_GRADE, grade};
}
```

And then in the reducer:

```
case types.SET_PICKER_GRADE: {
  const {grade} = action;
  return {...state, grade};
}
```

Otherwise if you have very many possible keys and want to create a more generic action, then this should work:

```
export function setPicker(key, value) {
  return {type: types.SET_PICKER, key, value};
}
```

And then in the reducer:

```
case types.SET_PICKER {
  const {key, value} = action;
  const nextState = {};
  nextState[key] = value;
  return {...state, ...nextState};
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! In my case I have multiple keys so I used the last approach.